# How to call a different value for each element in a list in R

Tags: r, list, apply

I have a list with 29 data frames. 
I am trying to do a simple transformation with `ifelse()`, that looks something like this: 
`with(df, ifelse(col1 > x, col1 <- col1-y, col1<-col1+y))`

The one thing I can't seem to get is how to change that `x` and `y` value so that a different value is used for each data frame in the list.

Here's a quick reproducible example of what I've got so far .. but I want to call different values for x and y from a data frame (e.g. info)

```
df.1 <- data.frame("df"=rep(c(1), times=4),"length"=c(10:7))
df.2 <- data.frame("df"=rep(c(2),times=4),"length"=c(8:11))
df.3 <- data.frame("df"=rep(c(3),times=4),"length"=c(9:12))

list <- list(df.1,df.2,df.3)

info <- data.frame(x=rep(c(8.5,9.5,10.5)), y=rep(c(1,1.5,2)))

# using static number for x & y but wanting these to be grabbed from the above df and change 
# for each list

x <- 8
y <- 1
lapply(list, function(df) {
  df <- with(df, ifelse(length > x, 
                            length <- length-y,
                            length <- length+y)) })
```

Any and all help/insight is appreciated!

**Edited to add clarification:**

I would like the rows to match up with lists.

E.g. Row 1 in Info (x=8.5, y=1) is used in the function and applied just to the first data frame in the list (df.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to pass more than one value to `lapply`, you must use `mapply` instead.

```
mapply(
  function(df, x, y) {
    #print("df")
    #print(df)
    #print("x")
    #print(x)
    #print("y")
    #print(y)
    with(df, ifelse(length > x, length <- length - x, length <- length + y)) 
  },
  list,
  info$x,
  info$y
)
```

I've left some debugging in the code which can enabled in case you want to see how it works.

Comment: Ahh, okay this makes sense. One follow up, this produces a data frame with the results .. how do I get it to put the new output in the same old list of data frames? Thanks!

Comment: Ignore the question in that comment, realized I just had to include ```;return(df)```

Comment: & ```SIMPLIFY = FALSE ```